# spark scala read avro multiple paths with schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, path, schema, avro

How can I read with spark+scala list of paths with defined schema?

In spark+python (pyspark), I can do:

```
sample_paths = [path1, path2, ..., pathN]

avro_schema = """{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.example.data",
  "name": "exampleTable",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "user", "type": ["string", "null"]}, 
    {"name": "name", "type": ["string", "null"]}, 
    {"name": "id", "type": ["long", "null"]}]
}"""

spark.read.format("avro").load(sample_paths, avroSchema=avro_schema, header=True)
```

and it works ...

but in scala if I do:

```
val samplePaths = List(path1, path2, ..., pathN)

spark.read.format("avro").load(samplePaths: _*, avroSchema=avro_schema, header=True)
```

then I get an error:

```
error: overloaded method value load with alternatives:
  (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  ()org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String, avroSchema: String, header: Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way in spark+scala:

```
spark
  .read
  .format("avro")
  .option("avroSchema", avro_schema)
  .option("header", "true")
  .load(samplePaths: _*)
```